# Facebook share shows correct share url when I use domain name and on ip address

Tags: facebook, share

when I share something like

mydomain.com/mypage/xxx

facebook gives me correct share link

but when i try

111.222.333.444/mypage/xxx

it shares the home page of my site insted of the page I referred to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing ip-based url's sounds like a bad idea. Why do you need to do that?  As a workaround, you could use a URL shortener like [bit.ly](http://bit.ly) with your ip-based url.  If you really need to share a URL with an IP address, [log a bug with Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs).